# How to change content on hover

Tags: html, css

I've been playing around with this, and I thought it would be pretty simple. What I'm trying to do is hover over the 'NEW' label. Once in its hover state, change the content from 'NEW' to 'ADD' using only CSS.

```css
body{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.item{
    width: 30px;
}
a{
    text-decoration:none;
}
.label {
    padding: 1px 3px 2px;
    font-size: 9.75px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-color: #bfbfbf;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.label.success {
    background-color: #46a546;
}

.item a p.new-label span{
  position: relative;
  content: 'NEW'
}
.item:hover a p.new-label span{
  display: none;
}
.item:hover a p.new-label{
  content: 'ADD';
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
    <a href="">
         <p class="label success new-label"><span class="align">New</span></p>
    </a>
</div>
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fLMSd/8/) to show you what I'm working with.

Comment: You can't change the content of an existing element using CSS.

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/G9LKK/

Comment: This is not what CSS was made for. If you want interactive stuff, use the right tool for that: JavaScript.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The CSS [content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content) property along with `::after` and `::before` pseudo-elements have been introduced for this.

```
.item:hover a p.new-label:after{
    content: 'ADD';
}
```

Example:

```css
body{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.item{
    width: 30px;
}
a{
    text-decoration:none;
}
.label {
    padding: 1px 3px 2px;
    font-size: 9.75px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-color: #bfbfbf;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.label.success {
    background-color: #46a546;
}

.item a p.new-label span{
  position: relative;
  content: 'NEW'
}
.item:hover a p.new-label span{
  display: none;
}
.item:hover a p.new-label:after{
  content: 'ADD';
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
    <a href="">
         <p class="label success new-label"><span class="align">New</span></p>
    </a>
</div>
```

Here is the original [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fLMSd/14/)

Comment: +1 you beat me to it: http://jsfiddle.net/fLMSd/16/ Just thought I would show my fiddle as well, as it is stripped down to the bare essential

Comment: Actually, there was going to be a proposal for CSS3's `content` to be able to alter the content of actual elements, but that was abandoned. It's CSS2's `content` that only operates on generated content.

Answer (score 16):

This exact example is present on mozilla developers page:

[::after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after#Tooltips)

As you can see it even allows you to create tooltips! :) Also, instead of embedding the actual text in your CSS, you may use `content: attr(data-descr);`, and store it in `data-descr="ADD"` attribute of your HTML tag (which is nice because you can e.g translate it)

CSS `content` can only be usef with `:after` and `:before` pseudo-elements, so you can try to proceed with something like this:

```
.item a p.new-label span:after{
  position: relative;
  content: 'NEW'
}
.item:hover a p.new-label span:after {
  content: 'ADD';
}
```

> The CSS :after pseudo-element matches a virtual last child of the
>   selected element. Typically used to add cosmetic content to an
>   element, by using the content CSS property. This element is inline by
>   default.

Answer (score 12):

```css
.label:after{
    content:'ADD';
}
.label:hover:after{
    content:'NEW';
}
```

```html
<span class="label"></span>
```

Answer (score 10):

This may help someone trying to avoid :before or :after pseudo elements altogether (for whatever reason) in changing text on hover. You can add both texts in the HTML, but vary the CSS 'display' property based on hover. Assuming the second text 'Add' has a class named 'add-label'; here is a little modification:

```
span.add-label{
 display:none;
}
.item:hover span.align{
 display:none;
}
.item:hover span.add-label{
 display:block;
}
```

Here is a demonstration on codepen: https://codepen.io/ifekt/pen/zBaEVJ