# FontAwesome Icons in css content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

So I just asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19058421/hover-change-content-with-css), and it works fine. But when I thought; what if I try to put font-icons or glyphs into css' content property?

Here's [**the fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/JfGVE/12/). So is this even possible, how do I get a fontawesome icons to render in css' content property?

```
.item a p.new-label span{
  position: relative;
  content: 'NEW'
}
.item:hover a p.new-label span{
  display: none;
}
.item:hover a p.new-label:after{
  content: '\f014';
}
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to set the font-family in your .item:hover and you'll be good to go.

http://jsfiddle.net/bhlaird/JfGVE/13/

```
.item:hover a p.new-label:after {
    font-family:FontAwesome;
    content:'\f014';
}
```

Comment: Perfect in my case using bootstrap font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings' did it for me