# Trying to change content of div with css :hover

Tags: html, css

I know I have seen this done but I can't remember where I saw it.  I'm trying to change the content of a div when the css :hover is triggered.

Here's the css  I'm trying to get to work:

```
 .mWin_close:hover div.new-label:after {
     content: 'X';
 }
```

html

```
 <div id="mClose" class="mWin_close"></div>
```

Comment: so what's your question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hover change content with css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19058421/hover-change-content-with-css)

Comment: We can't diagnose this without the HTML & CSS to see it "not working".

Comment: This code isn't adding 'X' to the div html

Comment: Where is `div.new-label`?

Comment: ummm, I thought it would just add new-label class to the existing div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS cannot add a class to a div, which as you said in the comments, is what you were expecting it to do.
Just change your CSS like so:

```css
     
.mWin_close:after {
   content: 'Hover over me! :D';
}    
.mWin_close:hover:after {
   content: 'X';
}
```

```html
<div id="mClose" class="mWin_close"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `content` property with `:after` and `:before` to manipulate what is showed on hover.. i dont know what your classes are called so i just made my own. Hope this helps.

```css
   
.mWin_close{
  width:30px;
}

.mWin_close:after {
   content: 'Y';
}    
.mWin_close:hover:after {
   content: 'X';
}
```

```html
<div id="mClose" class="mWin_close"></div>
```