# Using LESS to change text on hover is not working

Tags: html, css, less

I'm trying to change the text in my nav menu on hover using LESS.
I followed [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19058421/hover-change-content-with-css) but it's not working for me and I can't understand why.

Here is my html:

```
<nav class="sideNav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href=""><span>one</span></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><span>2</span></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><span>3</span></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><span>4</span></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><span>5</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

and my LESS:

```
li:nth-child(2) span{
      position: relative;
      content: '2';
    }
    li:nth-child(2):hover li:nth-child(2) span{
      display: none;
    }
    li:nth-child(2):hover li:nth-child(2):after{
      content: 'ADD';
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You cannot select the 1st element using second element in CSS, `content` only works with pseudo-elements. BTW your code is vanilla CSS, not LESS. I recommend you to look for JS solution.

Comment: Thats also not LESS? It's CSS.

Comment: That was a typo. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this.

```css
li:nth-child(2):hover span {
  text-indent: -9999px;
}
li:nth-child(2):hover a:after {
  content: 'ADD';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.sideNav a,
.sideNav span {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<nav class="sideNav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href=""><span>one</span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href=""><span>2</span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href=""><span>3</span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href=""><span>4</span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href=""><span>5</span></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Hey, I spoke too soon. While the text changes as required, the links stopped working after implementing this.

Comment: Ive updated my answer... sorry didn't check the anchors :)

Answer (score 0):

The other answer still didn't fix the links for me. This fixed it though.

HTML

```
<li class="hoverable">
                <span class="normal"><a href="">2</a></span><span class="hover"><a href="">two</a></span>
            </li>
```

CSS

```
      .hoverable {
        cursor:default;
        text-decoration:none;
      }
      .hoverable .hover {
        display:none;
      }
      .hoverable:hover .normal {
        display:none;
      }
      .hoverable:hover .hover {
        display:inline;
      }
```