# How to make a text appear on hover and another disappear using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have to build a card with text (that's not the problem) the problem is that the text on the card has to disappear on hover because a different text should appear on hover.

I made a simplified version of my code, so you don't have to look at that mess XD.

Thank you very much, if you could help<3

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}


/* #45B8AC card color */

body {
  background-color: #D65076;
}

.card {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  left: 25%;
  top: 25%;
  background: #FF6F61;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.6s;
}

.card-h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
}

.card-text {
  font size: 17px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 150px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.card:hover+.hide {
  background: black;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-h1">
      BergWerk
    </div>

    <div class="card-text">
      Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident <br> modi labore esse aliquam rem, voluptatem porro veritatis assumenda <br> inventore neque quas dolore maiores deleniti officia dignissimos autem <br> eum nihil aliquid minima
      debitis corporis id quam! Error debitis nulla <br> explicabo repellendus quo consequatur vel hic illo, voluptates reprehe <br>
    </div>

    <div class="hide">
      <h1>Hello WORLD</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: The primary reason this doesn't work is because `.card` and `.hide` aren't siblings. You've used an adjacent sibling selector.  You're missing a closing div tag, by the way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change content on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19058421/how-to-change-content-on-hover)

Comment: I also strongly suggest moving away from all that absolute positioning. It's probably not necessary and makes your layout much more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: how about using opacity when it hover? set one div to opacity:0 and other to be 1. It work really well for me

Comment: @isherwood yea thx for the advice iam new to css etc but i will try my best <3

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works. "TY" comments aren't appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

I think this would be a simple way to implement what you want. I'm covering the main text with the text you want to appear on hover, making it invisible, and then making it visible again only on hover.

```css
body{
  background-color: #D65076;
}

.parent, .cover{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #FF6F61;
}

.parent{
  position: relative;
}

.cover{
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.cover:hover{
  opacity: 100;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  Some text would go in here
  <div class="cover"> 
    The hover text would go here
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used jQuery, Hope this helps!

```js
$('.card-text').hover(function() {
  $('.hide').css("display", "block");
  $('.card-text').css("display", "none");
})

$('.hide').hover(function() {
  $('.card-text').css("display", "block");
  $('.hide').css("display", "none");
})
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}


/* #45B8AC card color */

body {
  background-color: #D65076;
}

.card {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  left: 25%;
  top: 25%;
  background: #FF6F61;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.6s;
}

.card-h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
}

.card-text {
  font size: 17px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 150px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.card:hover+.hide {
  background: black;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-h1">
      BergWerk
    </div>

    <div class="card-text">
      Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident <br> modi labore esse aliquam rem, voluptatem porro veritatis assumenda <br> inventore neque quas dolore maiores deleniti officia dignissimos autem <br> eum nihil aliquid minima
      debitis corporis id quam! Error debitis nulla <br> explicabo repellendus quo consequatur vel hic illo, voluptates reprehe <br>
    </div>

    <div class="hide">
      <h1>Hello WORLD</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```